# Share uploaded image to canvas between multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, socket.io

I am doing a collaborative app with node and sockets where I can upload images to canvas. If one of the connected users uploads a image, how can I make that image to be drawn to all the connected users?

This is what i tried:

**Client**

```
socket.on('img', 
        function() {
        console.log("Image uploaded");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 105, 50);
        }
    );

function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
    function readImage() {
        if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
            var FR= new FileReader();
            FR.onload = function(e) {
               var img = new Image();
               img.onload = function() {
                   var image = ctx.drawImage(img, 105, 50);
                   console.log("sendimg: ");
                   socket.emit('img');
               };
               img.src = e.target.result;
            };       
            FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
        }
    }
    el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

**Server**

```
socket.on('img',
      function() {
      console.log("Image Uploaded");
        socket.broadcast.emit('img');
      }
    );
```

Comment: You are sending a message about the image, but you're not sending the image itself...

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Send the image somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you emit, you need to send the image data along as well. For example, you could send a base64 encoded version of the image:

```
img.onload = function() {
   var image = ctx.drawImage(img, 105, 50);
   console.log("sendimg: ");
   socket.emit('img', ctx.toDataURL());
};
```

You can then add an image with the `src` set to that data URL. [Different image formats are available if you prefer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

You then need to update your client to handle the parameter:

```
socket.on('img', function(dataURL) {
    console.log("Image uploaded");
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img, 105, 50);
    };
    img.src = dataURL;

});
```

And your server to pass it along:

```
socket.on('img', function(dataURL) {
    console.log("Image Uploaded");
    socket.broadcast.emit('img', dataURL);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've added the data URL as in your example, do I need to add something else in `img.src = e.target.result;` ?

Comment: No problem. You shouldn't need to alter that since it's the local copy of the image - it should still operate on `e.target.result`

Comment: There are many other things that can go wrong in the setup, my answer covers the problems that are visible based in the code you posted. I suggest logging the dataURL on the originator, the server, and the receiving client and ensure that everyone is seeing the URL. From there, it's just an issue of debugging why it isn't rendering properly.

Comment: I will try to figure it out what is still missing. Thank you for your update ;)

Comment: After I upload the image i get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: ctx.toDataURL is not a function at HTMLImageElement.img.onload` it points to `ctx.toDataURL()` in the first part of code in your answer.

Comment: I got it, instead of `socket.emit('img', toDataURL());` i changed to `socket.emit('img', e.target.result);` and it works now ;)